# Android SDK folder moved from ubuntu /home (ext4) directory to an NTFS drive and stopped working

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, file-permissions

I searched for the solution before I clicked on 'Ask Question' button, sadly I didn't find any solution.

I was running out of space. So I had to move the android sdk folder to an NTFS drive. I forgot that Ubuntu doesn't allow executing program from NTFS drive. So I moved it (actually copied) back to /home directory. And when I opened android studio, the SDK manager and Device Monitor was not opening. Out of curiosity I checked the properties of some of the executable files inside android sdk directory and I found out, the execution permission was removed from all the executables inside sdk directory because I moved it to an NTFS partition.

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: I would just redownload it. You can try going through all your files, `find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;` and `find . -type d chmod 755 {} \;`. But for the executables, there is no real way to search for them, you can use `chmod 777`.

Comment: Ok, I am going to re-install entire Android Studio. Can you please tell me how can I completely remove the Android Studio? I am on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Why would you `reinstall` androdi studio just to redownload the `Android SDK`? Just go download the SDK from the website.

Comment: I don't know I just have a hunch that the problem will persist even after redownloading. Ok I am downloading the SDK...

Comment: You did not mess with your installation. The SDK is separate.